# Linq GroupJoin c# 9 and .net 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble running the code below.

```
static void GroupJoinCategoriesAndProducts()
{
    using (var db = new Northwind())
    {
        var queryGroup = db.Categories
            .AsEnumerable()
            .GroupJoin(
                inner: db.Products,
                outerKeySelector: category => category.CategoryId,
                innerKeySelector: product => product.CategoryID,
                resultSelector: (c, matchingProducts) => new
                {
                    c.CategoryName,
                    Products = matchingProducts.OrderBy(p => p.ProductName)
                });

        foreach(var item in queryGroup)
        {
            WriteLine("{0} has {1} products.",
                arg0: item.CategoryName,
                arg1: item.Products.Count());
            foreach (var product in item.Products)
            {
                WriteLine($" {product.ProductName}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to run this exception occurs:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
  StackTrace:
   em Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   em Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)
   em Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(Boolean isAsync, String method)
   em Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   em Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   em Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   em Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   em System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   em Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   em System.Linq.Lookup`2.CreateForJoin(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   em System.Linq.Enumerable.<GroupJoinIterator>d__98`4.MoveNext()
   em LinqWithEFCore.Program.GroupJoinCategoriesAndProducts() em C:\Users\benhu\source\repos\TesteLinq\LinqWithEFCore\Program.cs:linha 29
   em LinqWithEFCore.Program.Main(String[] args) em C:\Users\benhu\source\repos\TesteLinq\LinqWithEFCore\Program.cs:linha 91
```

I tryed to run the code to see de database query result. the database is the northwind and the program doenst work.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the AsEnumerable. 
Use AsQueryable instead or don't use as... at all

Comment: Your problem is obvious, but answer simple question: does `Category` has navigation property `Products` or something like that?

Comment: `db.Categories.Include(c => c.Products).GroupJoin...`